# How to combine current element with the next element when elment is "-" in list in python?

Tags: python, list

I split a string into a list according to space. When element value is "-", I want to combine it with next elment.

For example,

`['x^3', 'x', '-', '4']` want to transformed to `['x^3', 'x', '-4']`.

`['-', 'x^3', 'x', '-', '4']` want to transformed to `['-x^3', 'x', '-4']`.

```
    b = "x^3 + x - 4".split(" ")
    b = [x for x in b if x != '+']
    #combine "-" with next element
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `replace` method of `str` would be useful:

```
s = "x^3 + x - 4"
new_s = s.replace('- ', '-').replace('+ ', '')
b = new_s.split(" ")
```

This is more elegant than using a `for` loop.
By the way, avoid using `for` loop and `append` of `list` if list comprehension can be used, because repeatedly calling `append` method is much slower than list comprehension.

Comment: why you omit '+'?

Comment: @MostafaZare, I think that +5 is the same 5. So, i omit it.

Answer (score 1):

With `for` loop you can do:

```
l1 = ['x^3', 'x', '-', '4']
l2 = ['-','x^3', 'x', '-', '4']


def func(x):
    new_x = []
    temp = None
    for i in x:
        if temp:
            i = temp+i
            temp = None
        if i == '-':
            temp = "-"
            continue

        new_x.append(i)

    return new_x

print(func(l1))
print(func(l2))
```

Output:

```
['x^3', 'x', '-4']
['-x^3', 'x', '-4']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main(arr: list) -> list:
    """Combines '-' with next element in list"""

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        try:
            if arr[i] == '-':
                arr[i + 1] = '-' + arr[i + 1]

                arr[i] = ''
        except IndexError:
            pass

    while True:
        if '' in arr:
            arr.remove('')
        else:
            break

    return arr


print(main(['-', 'x^3', 'x', '-', '4']))
```

Also you can use eval() for calculation:

```
b = "x**3 + x - 4"

x = 2

print(eval(b))
```